# How to create simple Portlet/WebPart in Mvc3

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to incorporate Portlet/Webpart in my project, Can anyone give me a simple demo for it that how can i achive it. I just want the basic knowledge for it so that i can initiate to code, simple coding example

thanks

Comment: Please define *portlet/webpart*. Also please show what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many good tutorials on how to create a portlet. E.g. 
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/147797/Webpart-Portlet-development-in-ASP-NET-MVC-Framewo

However, how you set it up depends on how your project is set up.

Comment: thanks for replying. I am looking for some simpler example. That link i have already checked.